# jQuery DataTables: Weird sorting with Dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, datatables

I need to format my Date Column in a certain format, but also needs to be sorted as a Date.  Its sorts it like text because of the .ToString.  Any advise how to sort it as Date but still keep the format?

View:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#dataTableHistory').DataTable({
            "iDisplayLength": 50,
            "order": [[0, "desc"]]
        });
    });
</script>

<table id="dataTableHistory" class="display">


    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>User</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        @foreach (var o in (List<CompoundSheetHistory>)ViewData["CompoundSheetHistories"])
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@o.DateCreated.ToString("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss")</td>
                <td>@o.User.FirstName</td>
                <td>@o.ActionDescription</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

On the first load, and when I click on the sort button, it sort the column, what seems to be like text.

[image: results of sorting]

Comment: It is trying to sort the text, maybe you can try to add another hidden column which has the sortable date format of yyyyMMddHHmmss?

Comment: Yes, it is sorting it as Text because of the .ToString.  The problem with the hidden column is, the user will not be able to sort it Asc or Desc

Comment: converting the text to a Date object and putting it into the table isn't an option for you?

Comment: no, that makes the system slow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend including the [`datetime-moment`](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/datetime-moment) plugin for datatables.
It has automatic type detection and sorting, you just have to provide the format.

```
$.fn.dataTable.moment('DD MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss');
```

```js
    $.fn.dataTable.moment('DD MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss');

    $(function() {
      $('#dataTableHistory').DataTable({
        "iDisplayLength": 50,
        "order": [
          [0, "desc"]
        ]
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.16/sorting/datetime-moment.js"></script>

<table id="dataTableHistory" class="display">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>User</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>22 Nov 2017 10:15:55</td>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Modified</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>22 Nov 2017 10:15:55</td>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Modified</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>22 Nov 2017 10:15:55</td>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Modified</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>21 Nov 2017 10:13:55</td>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Modified</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>12 Jan 2018 11:23:21</td>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Modified</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>11 Nov 2017 08:14:55</td>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Modified</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks @Shiffty, will give this a try!

Comment: Maybe a bit of an overkill for such a small task?

Comment: @lofihelsinki Adding two additional scripts might be a bit to much. But if he has already included moment for some reason or doesn't really care than I'd go with this attemp.

Comment: Sure, if `moment` is already part of the build, it's a good idea to use it here as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can provide the data as an array of objects and use the `colums.render` property.

Hold the date to display in `DateCreated` column and add another column (`DateToSort`) to  your dataset holding the number of milliseconds of the specific date (`date.getDate()`):

```
var data = [
  {
    DateCreated: date.ToString("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss"),
    DateToSort: date.getDate(),
    FirstName: ...,
    ActionDescription: ...
  },
  ...
]

$('#dataTableHistory').DataTable({
   data: data,
   columns: [
      {
         data: 'DateCreated',
         render: {
           _: 'DateCreated',
           sort: 'DateToSort'
         }
      },
      ...
   ]
});
```

You can check the [documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render)

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way, but a bit of a hack. Just include a hidden `span` at the start of the cell with a alphabetically sortable date format:

```
<tbody>
    @foreach (var o in (List<CompoundSheetHistory>)ViewData["CompoundSheetHistories"])
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
              <span style="display:none">@o.DateCreated.ToString("yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss")
              </span>@o.DateCreated.ToString("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss")
            </td>
            <td>@o.User.FirstName</td>
            <td>@o.ActionDescription</td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```